# `yarn add` installs stale version of local .tgz

Tags: yarnpkg, jupyter-lab

I am using yarn to install a package from a .tgz. When I update the package and install it again, yarn uses an old cached version of the package. Here is a [report from someone running into a similar problem](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/6811). If I try to delete the package from the cache, it gives me errors, and if I use `yarn cache clean` it will clear the whole cache, which is also not what I want.

The reason the package is changing is that I am developing it, and don't want to bump the version number every five minutes. I read maybe newer yarn versions take the package hash into account when installing, but I am stuck with version 1.22.1 (actually jlpm which is JupyterLab's vendored version of yarn).

Is there a way to say `yarn add package-0.1.0.tgz --dont-use-cache`? Or should I just skip yarn and use npm, or something else on top?

Answer (score 2):

I know it is a bit late, but if someone stumbles upon this topic. I finally get working by removing the `.tmp` folder in the yarn cache directory.

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/Yarn/v6/.tmp/*
yarn cache clean your-package
```

To get the yarn cache directory run the following cmd:

```
yarn cache dir
```